# How to set another Inline title in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need to change the `inline title` to something else other than the `verbose_name` of the class Meta in the model. Is there an attribute to achieve this?

Comment: See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name

Answer (score 117, accepted):

As documented, you need to set the values of your InlineModelAdmin subclass:

InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name - 
An override to the verbose_name found in the model’s inner Meta class.

InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name_plural - 
An override to the verbose_name_plural found in the model’s inner Meta class.

In this example, instead of the title 'Device' we use 'Phone':

```
class DeviceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Device
    verbose_name = "Phone"
    verbose_name_plural = "My Phones"
```

Comment: In most views  of Inlines `verbose_name_plural` is used.

Comment: `verbose_name` changes the title of each inline, while `verbose_name_plural` changes the main title of all inlines.

Comment: Hi @raratiru in my Django 2.1.3 the verbose_name doesn't work, the title of each inline is the __str__ of inline model. I'm still trying to find the way to change it. Do you or anybody know how? thanks!

Comment: @C.K. Hallo, as far as the documentation is concerned, I see that this option [is still there.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name). Probably it would be better to ask a new question where you could clearly illustrate all the details of the particular situation you are dealing with.