# How to customize Many-to-Many Inline in Admin Site

Tags: django, django-admin

This is how I've defined my models:

```
class Technology(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Technologies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = HTMLField()
    technology = models.ManyToManyField(Technology, related_name='projects')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And this is how I've defined the models in `admin.py`:

```
class TechnologyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Project.technology.through


@admin.register(Technology)
class TechnologyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TechnologyInline,
    ]
    exclude = [
        'technology',
    ]
```

And this is the result:
[image]

This is exactly what I need, but it's very ugly. Is it possible to customize the strings such as "Project-technology relationship: #1" and others?

Comment: What if you set `verbose_name='technology' and `verbose_name_plural='technologies'` for your `TechnologyInline`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set another Inline title in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807479/how-to-set-another-inline-title-in-django-admin)

Comment: Thanks. I've already set the verbose names. I'm asking about other strings such as "Project-technology relationship #1, #2, #3,...". I want to set an entirely different string for them.

Comment: I would also wish to don't show empty relations. A plus button to add them onm demand would be enough.